# How to fix this fine input and jquery error below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically the following code is causing your problem:

```
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden'); 
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden'); 
/// THIS LINE BELOW 
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(result + '<label>Image File: <input name="fileImage" class="fileImage" type="file"/></label><br/><br/><label><input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label><label><input type="button" name="imageClear" class="imageClear" value="Clear File"/></label>'); 
/// THIS LINE ABOVE 
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');
```

The above code is taken from the code that runs after a succesful/errorful upload has occured. This code proceeds to overwrite the form responsible for uploading the image. Now this is fine for successes because as the interface uses seperate forms for each image... once you get a success you don't reuse that form again (so no error on the server side for subsequent uploads).

However, when the image upload errors or cancels,I try and reuse that form to upload the image again? If so you have overwritten and removed the numimage input html:

```
<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='" numimage "' />
```

Which means that I would get an error as this field doesn't exist anymore.

My question is that how can I fix this? How can I fix the problem so I don't lose the value in the hidden input form and that the field still exists?

UPDATE:

Below is the image input form:

```
    var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
"<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='" + numimage + "' />" +
"<div class='display_content_image'>" +
"<p class='imagef1_upload_process' align='center'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /><br/></p>" +
"<p class='imagef1_upload_form' align='center'><br/><label>" + 
"Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
"<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
"</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" +
"<input type='reset' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>" +
"</p><p class='listImage' align='left'></p>" +
"<iframe class='upload_target_image' name='upload_target_image' src='#' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></div></form>");

$image.append($fileImage);
```

Below is the jquery code in full where it starts the image file upload:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.display_content_image').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

        $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow
              $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
    return stopImageUpload(2);

});      


  return true;
```

}

Below is the jquery code in full where it stops the image file upload:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      var replaceForm = function(result) { 
  $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(result + '<label>Image File: <input name="fileImage" class="fileImage" type="file"/></label><br/><br/><label><input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label><label><input type="button" name="imageClear" class="imageClear" value="Clear File"/></label>');
} 

var updateForm = function(result) { 
  $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.display_content_image').html(result);
} 

var displayInfo;

      if (success === 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
        displayInfo = replaceForm;      
         }
      else if (success === 2){
          result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was canceled</span><br/><br/>';
          displayInfo = updateForm;    
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span><br/><br/>';
         displayInfo = updateForm;  
      }
      displayInfo(result); 


      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:
`$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(...)` is clobbering the contents of the form element.  If the existing code works for success conditions then you should leave it as is.  When you're handling the error condition (ideally using the `error` callback if you have a RESTful API), rather than overridding the entire form you should have a specific element for the error message which is then populated.  Something like:

`$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.error_message').html(msg).show();`

**Sample for update:**

```
var replaceForm = function(result) {
  //existing code to replace full form content
}
var updateForm = function(result) {
  //new code to display error message
}
var displayFunk;
if (success === 1){
  result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span><br/><br/>';      
  $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
  displayFunk = replaceForm;
}
else if (success === 2){
  result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was canceled</span><br/><br/>';
  displayFunk = updateForm;
}
else {
  result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span><br/><br/>';
  displayFunk = updateForm;
}
displayFunk(result);
```

Notice the `===` for comparison which avoids some JavaScript automatic coercion.  This will head off bugs when doing things like comparing a value to `1`. You'd also be best off avoiding the way you're using a return value, but at the least you may want to use pseudo constants/enum and a dispatch table style object.

Comment: Do I include the line of code on the error message and remove the other line of code where it is clobbering the contents or do I need both lines of code?

Comment: I inluded the file input form so you can see what the form looks like. Im guessing I need to change the form slighlty?

Comment: You should really have that form HTML left as HTML in a page/used as a template.  If you really want to go with creating it in JavaScript it would be far clearer if you do it more modularly.  Leave the existing code (at least for now) if it's working the way you want, but only call it on success.  When there's an error, then don't call that code but call the error message display code.  So yes, you need both lines.

Comment: Just to make sure is`.error_message` simply a `<p>` paragraph tag with the class error_message, that is all .error_message needs to be right? Also result is that variable which displays the messages so should it be `$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.error_message').html(result).show();`? This does both successful and failed messages. I included jquery code above on possible messages that may be recieved

Comment: Yes any container will work well, `p` would make sense for a single message.  You may want to for now put the display of the messages in the conditional that you have.  I'll update the answer with a sample.

Comment: Ok I set up your code, I just need to make sure that for the error message suppose to be `$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.error_message').html(res‌ult).show();` or is it suppose to be `$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').find('.error_message').html(msg).show();`

Comment: Ok, There is a slight probelem. You were so close mate. Ok this is what is happening. If I upload a file and then cancel it and then successfully uplaod the next file, then it works fine, the field still exists. But if I do the same procedure again (cancel the next upload and then successfully upload the next file), then it does what it was previously doing, and the hidden input must of been overwritten or removed. DO you have idea why this is happening?

Comment: The hidden input will be removed as soon as `success === 1`.  If you want to keep the hidden input after that you shouldn't override the whole form.  Change the process so that you never overwrite the form, but instead create a `div` or something similar within the form that the hidden input is not in, and then overwrite that.

Comment: If you don't mind can you give me another sample on what you have stated in your last comment so I can see what I have to do to overwrite a div and not the form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17037/discussion-between-matt-whipple-and-user1681039)